# Using box-drawing Unicode characters in batch files

Tags: unicode, cmd, special-characters

I am making a batch file that uses these characters:

```
˧ ˥ ˪ ˫
```

It is not working, it just terminates itself.
I have seen people use characters like this:

```
Å
```

It isnt the character but it turns into a character, can someone give me a list of these, shows the type of letter above and what it turns into?

Comment: What do you get when you run `chcp` from the console?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to write console batch files that use those characters, you need an editor that will save the batch file using the console's code page.  To check what that is, type:

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 437
```

This is the result for my US Windows system.  Western European versions of Windows will often be code page 850.

A good editor is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).  Set that encoding in the editor (Encoding, Character sets, Western European, OEM-US) and copy the following characters into it:

```
@echo off
echo ╔═╦═╗ ┌─┬─┐ ╓─╥─╖ ╒═╤═╕
echo ║ ║ ║ │ │ │ ║ ║ ║ │ │ │
echo ╠═╬═╣ ├─┼─┤ ╟─╫─╢ ╞═╪═╡
echo ║ ║ ║ │ │ │ ║ ║ ║ │ │ │
echo ╚═╩═╝ └─┴─┘ ╙─╨─╜ ╘═╧═╛
```

Save the file as `test.bat` and run it from the console:

```
C:\>test
╔═╦═╗ ┌─┬─┐ ╓─╥─╖ ╒═╤═╕
║ ║ ║ │ │ │ ║ ║ ║ │ │ │
╠═╬═╣ ├─┼─┤ ╟─╫─╢ ╞═╪═╡
║ ║ ║ │ │ │ ║ ║ ║ │ │ │
╚═╩═╝ └─┴─┘ ╙─╨─╜ ╘═╧═╛
```

When you open the file again in Notepad++, it is possible that you will see something like:

```
@echo off
echo ÉÍËÍ» ÚÄÂÄ¿ ÖÄÒÄ· ÕÍÑÍ¸
echo º º º ³ ³ ³ º º º ³ ³ ³
echo ÌÍÎÍ¹ ÃÄÅÄ´ ÇÄ×Ä¶ ÆÍØÍµ
echo º º º ³ ³ ³ º º º ³ ³ ³
echo ÈÍÊÍ¼ ÀÄÁÄÙ ÓÄÐÄ½ ÔÍÏÍ¾
```

Since there is no indication in the file what code page the characters in it represent, Notepad++ may choose the so-called `ANSI` code page.  On US Windows that is `Windows-1252`.  Just select the `OEM-US` encoding again to display it properly.

Comment: Mark, just wanted to say a big thanks.  The Notepad++ trick worked beautifully to fix an issue we were having with a large Xcopy batch file that had a bunch of Norwegian characters in the file names.  The bat would say "File Not Found" on those files but a straight cmd line of one would work fine.  Doing what you said allowed me to run the full batch file and it worked beautifully....thanks again!

Comment: On my system, the `ÉÍËÍ» ÚÄÂÄ¿ ÖÄÒÄ· ÕÍÑÍ` problem didn't happen, but when I switch to `chcp 437`, my console becomes much flatter and less tall.

Comment: Placing this text into my batch file with chcp 437 worked, however that broke all my findstr and call commands.

Answer (score 3):

The characters you can use depend on the console codepage that is set. You can see it with `chcp`. On many systems it's 850 or 437. You can then look up the characters in [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)  or find one that supports the characters you need and use `chcp` in your batch file to set it early on.

Note though that this is a setting for the process, so if someone needs to continue working with the console window afterwards it might not be nice to change their drapes to another colour. Also code page 65001 is UTF-8, but has a set of problems and drawbacks that make it rather tricky to use.

Note also that Notepad is not a useful text editor for writing batch files that need more than ASCII, because the legacy encoding in the non-console part of Windows is a different one. This might be what you mean that Å turns into another character.

Comment: It is also worth noting that batch scripts must be ANSI encoded. Unicode is not supported.

Comment: Thank you, but the characters are turning out weird. It turns out to the special character that turns it into the Unicode character. Can you send me a list of  characters that turn into Unicode characters?

Comment: @JacobRocks12, that honestly makes no sense. There are no characters that turn into Unicode characters, per se, except the characters themselves. Also »weird« is not a very useful description of your problem.

Comment: The character list look like @MarkTolonen said below:
`@echo off
echo ÉÍËÍ» ÚÄÂÄ¿ ÖÄÒÄ· ÕÍÑÍ¸
echo º º º ³ ³ ³ º º º ³ ³ ³
echo ÌÍÎÍ¹ ÃÄÅÄ´ ÇÄ×Ä¶ ÆÍØÍµ
echo º º º ³ ³ ³ º º º ³ ³ ³
echo ÈÍÊÍ¼ ÀÄÁÄÙ ÓÄÐÄ½ ÔÍÏÍ¾`
Can you send me a list of these?

Comment: You do realize that those are just the same bytes in another code page? You can just look up the character mappings of the respective code pages and make a table yourself. Or a quick script that takes each byte and converts it to both code pages. The solution here is not to try to learn some arcane making between characters, but to use a text editor that allows you to specify the encoding you want your text file in (as both I and Mark noted).

Comment: @JacobRocks12: You can use this little PowerShell snippet to get a listing: `$e=[Text.Encoding];$d=$e::Default;$o=$e::GetEncoding(+((chcp)-replace'.*?(?=\d+$)'));128..255|%{$d.GetString($_)+"="+$o.GetString($_)}`

Answer (score 1):

You just need this equivalences file that works in any text editor, including the standard Windows Notepad:

```
Notepad: ┌┬┐ ├┼┤ └┴┘ ─ │
cmd.exe: ÚÂ¿ ÃÅ´ ÀÁÙ Ä ³

Notepad: ╔╦╗ ╠╬╣ ╚╩╝ ═ ║
cmd.exe: ÉË» ÌÎ¹ ÈÊ¼ Í º
```

Copy this table into a text file, that you must save as Unicode encoding. Then, when you want to insert a character in your Batch file, just choose the one below the graphic char you want to show.

Note: These characters are correct for code pages 850 or 437.

This table was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106717/how-would-i-put-in-batch-files/34107955#34107955).

Comment: What about handling filenames that contain unicode characters beyond the 255 codepage range?