# How would I put ╚ in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, ascii

I am trying to make lines ( ╚╔ etc ) into my batch file, however inserting them directly into a batch file will result in some weird character that I didn't put in. I am using notepad++ to type these character via alt+200 or something depending on the character I want, Windows 10, and Command Prompt Version 10.0.10240

Are there any solutions?

Comment: I tested your problem using the accepted answer in the duplicate question, and it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Unicode characters in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413489/using-unicode-characters-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 2):

You just need this equivalences file:

```
Notepad: ┌┬┐ ├┼┤ └┴┘ ─ │
cmd.exe: ÚÂ¿ ÃÅ´ ÀÁÙ Ä ³

Notepad: ╔╦╗ ╠╬╣ ╚╩╝ ═ ║
cmd.exe: ÉË» ÌÎ¹ ÈÊ¼ Í º
```

Copy it into a text file, that you must save as Unicode encoding. Then, when you want to insert a character *in your Batch file*, just choose the one *below* the graphic char you want to show!

**Note**: These characters are correct for code pages 850 or 437.