# batch menu outlines and design

Tags: windows, batch-file

a while ago i were googling to find out how I could make a batch menu with a more "professional look" instead of using  symbols such as:

```
|=====|
|-----|
|_____|
```

to make outlines around a menu in batch.
but I had no luck.
today i randomly found this article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151204182221/https://http-server.carleton.ca/~dmcfet/menu.html

and it explains that by using ms-dos (edit.com) I can do this.
but as my computer is a 64 bit win 10. I dot have the edit.com so.... how could I make this kind of menu look by hand? `(printing special characters shown on left side of the header "STEP 3, Lines, Lines, Lines.")`

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28426204/5022761)

Comment: thanks man. this is exactily what im looking for .D

Comment: No problem, but that was on the first page of google. You should put a bit more research into your questions.

Comment: well.. it might because i didnt know what "keywords" to use. if i probably googled "charset" i would probably find it.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a batch + PowerShell menu maker I've been working on.  Set the values in the batch portion, and the PowerShell stuff will auto resize and reposition as needed.  When a selection is made, the console buffer restores its former contents, effectively vanishing the menu.

It looks like this:

[image: arrow navigated menu]

Here's the code.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```js
<# : Batch portion
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "menu[0]=Format C:"
set "menu[1]=Send spam to boss"
set "menu[2]=Truncate database *"
set "menu[3]=Randomize user password"
set "menu[4]=Download Dilbert"
set "menu[5]=Hack local AD"

set "default=0"

powershell -noprofile "iex (gc \"%~f0\" | out-string)"
echo You chose !menu[%ERRORLEVEL%]!.

goto :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

$menutitle = "=== MENU ==="
$menuprompt = "Use the arrow keys.  Hit Enter to select."

$maxlen = $menuprompt.length + 6
$menu = gci env: | ?{ $_.Name -match "^menu\[\d+\]$" } | %{
    $_.Value.trim()
    $len = $_.Value.trim().Length + 6
    if ($len -gt $maxlen) { $maxlen = $len }
}
[int]$selection = $env:default
$h = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
$w = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
$xpos = [math]::floor(($w - ($maxlen + 5)) / 2)
$ypos = [math]::floor(($h - ($menu.Length + 4)) / 3)

$offY = [console]::WindowTop;
$rect = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle `
    0,$offY,($w - 1),($offY+$ypos+$menu.length+4)
$buffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents($rect)

function destroy {
    $coords = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 0,$offY
    $Host.UI.RawUI.SetBufferContents($coords,$buffer)
}

function getKey {
    while (-not ((37..40 + 13 + 48..(47 + $menu.length)) -contains $x)) {
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
    }
    $x
}

# http://goo.gl/IAmdR6
function WriteTo-Pos ([string]$str, [int]$x = 0, [int]$y = 0,
    [string]$bgc = [console]::BackgroundColor, [string]$fgc = [Console]::ForegroundColor) {
    if($x -ge 0 -and $y -ge 0 -and $x -le [Console]::WindowWidth -and
        $y -le [Console]::WindowHeight) {
        $saveY = [console]::CursorTop
        $offY = [console]::WindowTop       
        [console]::setcursorposition($x,$offY+$y)
        Write-Host $str -b $bgc -f $fgc -nonewline
        [console]::setcursorposition(0,$saveY)
    }
}

function center([string]$what) {
    $what = "    $what  "
    $lpad = " " * [math]::max([math]::floor(($maxlen - $what.length) / 2), 0)
    $rpad = " " * [math]::max(($maxlen - $what.length - $lpad.length), 0)
    WriteTo-Pos "$lpad   $what   $rpad" $xpos $line blue yellow
}

function menu {
    $line = $ypos
    center $menutitle
    $line++
    center " "
    $line++

    for ($i=0; $item = $menu[$i]; $i++) {
        # write-host $xpad -nonewline
        $rtpad = " " * ($maxlen - $item.length)
        if ($i -eq $selection) {
            WriteTo-Pos "  > $item <$rtpad" $xpos ($line++) yellow blue
        } else {
            WriteTo-Pos " $i`: $item  $rtpad" $xpos ($line++) blue yellow
        }
    }
    center " "
    $line++
    center $menuprompt
    1
}

while (menu) {

    [int]$key = getKey

    switch ($key) {

        37 {}   # left or up
        38 { if ($selection) { $selection-- }; break }

        39 {}   # right or down
        40 { if ($selection -lt ($menu.length - 1)) { $selection++ }; break }

        # number or enter
        default { if ($key -gt 13) {$selection = $key - 48}; destroy; exit($selection) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FIX:
in order to create a menu like this. you will need to use an editor such as notepad++
open a new notepad ++ file. then goto format and select western europe OEM-US charset.

then simply go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character
and copy paste the symbols you want for your menu in notepad++ and save.

example: 
Displayed in notepad++ :

```
echo                                   ╔════════════════════════════╗
echo                                   ║Bill register/database Menu ║
echo                                   ╠════════════════════════════╣
echo                                   ║   1. -Register a bill      ║
echo                                   ║   2. -Check Bill Info      ║
echo                                   ║   3. Set payment           ║
echo                                   ╚════════════════════════════╝
```

displayed in normal notepad :

```
echo                                   ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
echo                                   ºBill register/database Menu º
echo                                   ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹
echo                                   º   1. -Register a bill      º
echo                                   º   2. -Check Bill Info      º
echo                                   º   3. Set payment           º
echo                                   ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
```

so as you can see. it works with normal notepad too. but its easier to work with it in notepad++ as it displays what it actually look like.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to worry about code pages or file encodings at all.

When you are on windows 10 you can use the [Character Set - DEC Line Drawing Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#designate-character-set)
This uses ansi-escape sequences to show borders.
The border characters are represented by the characters `jklmnqtuvwx`.

```
for /F "delims=#" %%E in ('"prompt #$E# & for %%E in (1) do rem"') do set "\e=%%E"

REM *** Enable DEC Line Drawing Mode
echo %\e%(0

echo lqqk
echo x  x
echo x  x
echo mqqnqqk
echo    x  x
echo    mqqj

REM *** Enable ASCII Mode (Default)
echo %\e%(B
```

The output is

```
┌──┐
│  │
│  │
└──┼──┐
   │  │
   └──┘
```

Answer (score 0):

for Notepad with **ASCII** and **CHCP 1250** / **CHCP 1252** characters are:

**`É Í » ş Č Ľ`**