# Where do the options go?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, menu, interactive

I'm trying to upgrade a simple batch menu file to an hybrid batch/powershell hybrid. I came across this question - [batch menu outlines and design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977487/batch-menu-outlines-and-design/34983868#34983868) - which has a nice Powershell interface. However, I don't understand how to set the menu options properly! Can you please elucidate me?

The code is as follows:

```
<# : Batch portion # Original Code by rojo@StackOverflow 
REM  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo)
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "menu[0]=Open GenNBO Helper"
set "menu[1]=Open Jmol@NBO  Viewer Helper"
set "menu[2]=Open Jmol *"
set "menu[3]=Start NBO"
set "menu[4]=Start Multiwfn"
set "menu[5]=EXIT"

set "default=5"

powershell -noprofile "iex (gc \"%~f0\" | out-string)"
echo Option Selected: !menu[%ERRORLEVEL%]!.

goto :EOF

:GENNBO
CLS
ECHO Starting GenNbo Helper v1.33
cd L:\GennboHelper\
start GennboHelper_1.33.jar
GOTO MENU
#JMOLNBO 
:JMOLNBO
CLS
ECHO Starting JmolNbo Viewer Helper v2.1
cd L:\JmolNboVHelper2.1\
start JmolNbo21W.jar
GOTO MENU
#JMOL
:JMOL
CLS
ECHO Starting Jmol v14.30.1
cd L:\Jmol-14.30.1-binary\jmol-14.30.1
start Jmol.jar
GOTO MENU
#NBO
:NBO
CLS
ECHO Starting NBO 6.0 Environment CMD
cd L:\nbo6\
start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c L:\Portland\PGI\win64\19.10\pgi_dos.bat
GOTO MENU
#MWFN
:MWFN
CLS
ECHO Starting Multiwfn
L:\Multiwfn
start L:\Multiwfn\Multiwfn.exe
GOTO MENU

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

$menutitle = "=== MENU ==="
$menuprompt = "Use the arrow keys.  Hit Enter to select."

$maxlen = $menuprompt.length + 6
$menu = gci env: | ?{ $_.Name -match "^menu\[\d+\]$" } | %{
    $_.Value.trim()
    $len = $_.Value.trim().Length + 6
    if ($len -gt $maxlen) { $maxlen = $len }
}
[int]$selection = $env:default
$h = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
$w = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width
$xpos = [math]::floor(($w - ($maxlen + 5)) / 2)
$ypos = [math]::floor(($h - ($menu.Length + 4)) / 3)

$offY = [console]::WindowTop;
$rect = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle `
    0,$offY,($w - 1),($offY+$ypos+$menu.length+4)
$buffer = $Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents($rect)

function destroy {
    $coords = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 0,$offY
    $Host.UI.RawUI.SetBufferContents($coords,$buffer)
}

function getKey {
    while (-not ((37..40 + 13 + 48..(47 + $menu.length)) -contains $x)) {
        $x = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
    }
    $x
}

# goo.gl/IAmdR6
function WriteTo-Pos ([string]$str, [int]$x = 0, [int]$y = 0,
    [string]$bgc = [console]::BackgroundColor, [string]$fgc = [Console]::ForegroundColor) {
    if($x -ge 0 -and $y -ge 0 -and $x -le [Console]::WindowWidth -and
        $y -le [Console]::WindowHeight) {
        $saveY = [console]::CursorTop
        $offY = [console]::WindowTop       
        [console]::setcursorposition($x,$offY+$y)
        Write-Host $str -b $bgc -f $fgc -nonewline
        [console]::setcursorposition(0,$saveY)
    }
}

function center([string]$what) {
    $what = "    $what  "
    $lpad = " " * [math]::max([math]::floor(($maxlen - $what.length) / 2), 0)
    $rpad = " " * [math]::max(($maxlen - $what.length - $lpad.length), 0)
    WriteTo-Pos "$lpad   $what   $rpad" $xpos $line blue yellow
}

function menu {
    $line = $ypos
    center $menutitle
    $line++
    center " "
    $line++

    for ($i=0; $item = $menu[$i]; $i++) {
        # write-host $xpad -nonewline
        $rtpad = " " * ($maxlen - $item.length)
        if ($i -eq $selection) {
            WriteTo-Pos "  > $item <$rtpad" $xpos ($line++) yellow blue
        } else {
            WriteTo-Pos " $i`: $item  $rtpad" $xpos ($line++) blue yellow
        }
    }
    center " "
    $line++
    center $menuprompt
    1
}

while (menu) {

    [int]$key = getKey

    switch ($key) {

        37 {}   # left or up
        38 { if ($selection) { $selection-- }; break }

        39 {}   # right or down
        40 { if ($selection -lt ($menu.length - 1)) { $selection++ }; break }

        # number or enter
        default { if ($key -gt 13) {$selection = $key - 48}; destroy; exit($selection) }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason to mix Bat/CMD with powershell code? this type of thing is usually easier to do in _one or the other_. my preference is PoSh because it reads much more easily & is therefore easier to understand.

Comment: No reason other than I was just trying out this solution. I have zero experience with PoSh

Comment: ah! a learning experience. [*grin*] i would stick with one or the other. mixing them tends to be needlessly complicated.

Comment: Nonetheless, I would like to try this way just for kicks! So, any helpful suggestion regarding the present code would be most appreciated!

Comment: i have not done Bat stuff for ... decades. i will let others dig thru that nasty, confusing, poorly documented rats nest that is CMD/Bat coding ... [*grin*]

Comment: In that case, just by picking up the PoSh part of the script I posted, would be so kind as to explain me how you would, in PoSh, make that very same menu?

Comment: please take a look at my Answer for one way to use PoSh for a text menu system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after the `powershell ...` line, you just echo the selected menu point. You need to translate it into a `goto` like `if "!menu[%errorlevel%]!"=="Open GenNBO Helper" goto :GENNBO` etc (one line for each menu entry).

I suggest to change the labels instead and use just one `goto`:

```
powershell ...
echo Option Selected: !menu[%ERRORLEVEL%]!.
goto :menu%errorlevel%
goto :eof

:menu0
REM formerly :GENNBO
CLS
...
goto :menu

:menu1
REM formerly :JMOLNBO
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

this uses powershell with no CMD/Bat stuff at all. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- defines a function named `Get-MenuChoice`
  this simply displays a menu based on the provided array of menu items. then it gets a response that matches the array index of one of those items OR an `x` for exit.
- defines a menu list as an array
- sets the user `$Choice` to nothing
- starts a `while` loop
- uses the function to get a valid choice
- uses the `switch` construct to decide what to do for each choice
- writes "do the thing" that matches the choice
  you will need to add your own code here. it will likely be `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter.
- exits if the choice is `Exit`

here's the code ...

```
function Get-MenuChoice
    {
    [CmdletBinding ()]
    Param
        (
        [Parameter (
            Mandatory,
            Position = 0
            )]
            [string[]]
            $MenuList,

        [Parameter (
            Position = 1
            )]
            [string]
            $Title,

        [Parameter (
            Position = 2
            )]
            [string]
            $Prompt = 'Please enter a number from the above list or "x" to exit '

        )

    $ValidChoices = 0..$MenuList.GetUpperBound(0) + 'x'
    $Choice = ''
    while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
        {
        Write-Host $Title
        foreach ($Index in 0..$MenuList.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
            Write-Host ('{0} - {1}' -f $Index, $MenuList[$Index])
            }
        $Choice = Read-Host -Prompt $Prompt
        Write-Host ''

        if ($Choice -notin $ValidChoices)
            {
            [System.Console]::Beep(1000, 300)
            Write-Warning ''
            Write-Warning ('    [ {0} ] is not a valid selection.' -f $Choice)
            Write-Warning '    Please try again.'
            Write-Warning ''

            $Choice = ''

            pause
            }
        }

    # send it out to the caller
    if ($Choice -eq 'x')
        {
        'Exit'
        }
        else
        {
        $Choice
        }
    } # end >>> function Get-MenuChoice


$MenuList = @(
    'Open GenNBO Helper'
    'Open Jmol@NBO  Viewer Helper'
    'Open Jmol *'
    'Start NBO'
    'Start Multiwfn'
    )

$Choice = ''
while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
    {
    $Choice = Get-MenuChoice -MenuList $MenuList
    switch ($Choice)
        {
        0 {
            'Do the [ {0} ] thing.' -f $MenuList[$Choice]
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            break
            }
        1 {
            'Do the [ {0} ] thing.' -f $MenuList[$Choice]
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            break
            }
        2 {
            'Do the [ {0} ] thing.' -f $MenuList[$Choice]
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            break
            }
        3 {
            'Do the [ {0} ] thing.' -f $MenuList[$Choice]
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            break
            }
        4 {
            'Do the [ {0} ] thing.' -f $MenuList[$Choice]
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            break
            }
        'Exit' {
            break
            }
        default {
            'There is something wrong. [ {0} ] does not match any listed choice.' -f $Choice
            pause

            $Choice = ''
            }
        } # end >>> switch ($Choice)
    } # end >>> while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
```

output ...

```
0 - Open GenNBO Helper
1 - Open Jmol@NBO  Viewer Helper
2 - Open Jmol *
3 - Start NBO
4 - Start Multiwfn
Please enter a number from the above list or "x" to exit : 5

WARNING: 
WARNING:     [ 5 ] is not a valid selection.
WARNING:     Please try again.
WARNING: 
Press Enter to continue...: 

0 - Open GenNBO Helper
1 - Open Jmol@NBO  Viewer Helper
2 - Open Jmol *
3 - Start NBO
4 - Start Multiwfn
Please enter a number from the above list or "x" to exit : 3

Do the [ Start NBO ] thing.
Press Enter to continue...: 

0 - Open GenNBO Helper
1 - Open Jmol@NBO  Viewer Helper
2 - Open Jmol *
3 - Start NBO
4 - Start Multiwfn
Please enter a number from the above list or "x" to exit : x
```