# Unicode symbols in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

If I type this command into a cmd: "*echo █*", then it displays the " █ " symbol. But if I type the command "*echo █*" into a batch (.bat) file I get what is shown in the pic below.

[image]

How do I fix it? I only need the " █ " symbol, but optionally I would also need:
◧  ,  ◙  ,  ▤  ,  ▣  ,  ⍁  ,  ⍂

Comment: I may have a solution for you that relates to the Char Encoding of your file. May I ask, are you using Notepad++ by any chance and what number does it return if you just type chcp in cmd prompt?

Comment: also possible (unconvenient and ugly, but works): on command prompt add the char to your batchfile (`echo █>>mybatch.bat`), open it with notepad (or whatever) and copy/paste the char (whatever it may look like) to where you need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Unicode characters in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413489/using-unicode-characters-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can manually set the codepage to UTF-8 by typing `chcp 65001` at the top of your batch file.

Comment: `chcp 65001 >NUL`  so it doesn't output anything to the buffer.

Comment: Just to add, if you're saving the batch file in notepad, be sure to select "UTF-8" as the encoding in the Save/"Save as" dialog (as opposed to the default "ANSI" encoding).  Otherwise, when the file is read, the unicode character won't be read correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426204/4150884) may prove to be of use.

Remember to follow the instructions exactly.

*In other words, when it says copy into the document, they mean copy the chars and paste it into your document. Don't just convert your original document.*