# start bat command line but its name service with ç

Tags: batch-file

I need create a file bat for stop and start application service, but your name have a ç, and the command line no identify.
This is the code:

```
sc "\\hostname" stop "Serviço Carga Nfe"
sc "\\hostname" start "Serviço Carga Nfe"
```

Thanks

Comment: See [Using unicode characters in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413489/using-unicode-characters-in-batch-file).

Comment: Great, the code executed.
Thank you